# Correct way to do role based access control

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rbac

I am using nodejs, expressjs for my backend. I am trying to create a simple web application with **role base access control** but I am not sure if the way I am doing it is the correct/recommended way.

I have three roles, which are **super admin**, **admin** and **user**, and this is how I am doing it:

```
const checkRoleMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const getPostUserId = getPostFromDb(req.params.postId);
  const getPostUserData = getPostUserFromDb(getPostUserId);
  
  if(req.user.id === getPostUserData.id){
    /* next */
  }else if(req.user.permission === 'admin'){
    
    if(/* Check some other things & compare some other things */){
      /* next */
    }else{
      /* return unauthorized */     
    }
    
  }else if(req.user.permission === 'super admin') {
    /* next */     
  }else{
    /* return unauthorized */
  }
};


/* use checkRoleMiddleware on this route*/
app.post('/user/post/edit/:postId', checkRoleMiddleware, (req,res) => {
  /* Do something */
});
```

Is this the secure, correct/recommended way to do  **role base access control** in express app? What if I have more roles,  do I have to create more if statement? Is there any other better ways of doing it?

Comment: Perhaps with Casbin? https://casbin.org/docs/en/overview

Answer (score 0):

I could propose 3 different approaches to this problem (Apart to what you have now - as it's also a correct approach)

**Option 1** You could assign an integer value to each of the groups (super admin - 2, admin - 1, user - 0) and for the role based access control just check if users group value is higher than assigned one.

**Option 2** If you want to allow different roles to different actions, you can store an array of allowed roles/roles ids for each action, and check if it includes users role.

**Option 3** You can store action roles/user roles as binary value. For example you assign 1 to user, 2 to admin, 4 to super admin, 8 to super super admin. This way if you assign number 9 to user, they will be both USER and SUPER SUPER ADMIN allowing you to be more flexible about roles in the project. You can also allow specific roles for specific actions, so for example if you want action to be executed only by admin and higher, you can assign them a value of 14 (2+4+8).